# "Feeds are not available" - Wordpress error

Tags: wordpress, rss, wordpress-theming

I've got a wordpress site with 2 different themes running using the "Multiple Themes plugin". The main theme is a custom theme for the main website, the second theme is a blog which is found at www.themainwebsite.com/blog/.

The blog shows 'posts' while the main website works with a custom article name.

The blog looks fine, shows blog posts in index.php and single.php correctly. The only problem is that the rss link does not work. It goes to a page saying:

> Feeds are not available for this site. Please visit the website.

Here is an image of what happens when you follow the link.

[image: RSS Error]

The code I'm using is the website name and then "/feed/rss". It was working fine for the last few days but now it is showing the error I expressed. I'm confused as to why it was working and now I'm getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated thanks,

poncho

Answer (score 0):

It looks like rss feeds are disabled in your site.
Probably from a third party plugin or custom code in the theme.

Your attached image looks like the code in this article:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/

You might have some code in the theme like:

```
function wpb_disable_feed() {
wp_die( __('No feed available,please visit our <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>!') );
}

add_action('do_feed', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2_comments', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom_comments', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
```

I hope it helps!